# Problem converting date from a bootstrap datepicker to a different format

Tags: laravel, date, unix-timestamp

Working on an app whereby am capturing some input fields using bootstrap datepicker. Am displaying the format in dd/mm/yy format to the user which works fine. On the backend (build in Laravel PHP), I need to convert it to yy-mm-dd format which is the required format when storing the date field in the API.

In the controller when I dump the data I get 28/01/2019 but when I convert it I get 1970-01-01. What could be the issue?

**Markup**

```
<div class="form-line registar love {{ $errors->has('dob') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Date of Birth *" class="form-input dateTextBox" name="dob" id="dob" value="{{isset($user->dob) ? $user->dob : old('dob') }}" required>
</div>
```

**Javascript Logic (Bootstrap datpicker)**

```
 var maxBirthdayDate = new Date();
maxBirthdayDate.setFullYear( maxBirthdayDate.getFullYear() - 18 );
maxBirthdayDate.setMonth(11,31);
$( function() {
  $( "#dob" ).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    maxDate: maxBirthdayDate,
    yearRange: '1900:'+maxBirthdayDate.getFullYear(),
  });
});
```

**Controller Logic**

```
public function validateDate(Request $request){   
        //dd($request->dob);

        //28/02/2019 after dd() above

        //Convert 
        $dobCv = date("Y-d-m", strtotime($request->dob));

        dd($dobCv);

        //1970-01-01 after dd() above
}
```

Comment: Please post the data which is send from the `form` and your `expected format` that the date need to be conveted  **For Example**  FROM`'2018-01-31 23:32:06';`   TO :  `Jan 31st, 2018 11:32pm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use Carbon :

```
$dobCv = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $request->dob)->format('Y-m-d');
```

And don't forget the import :

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

Comment: , I have tried your suggection but I get this error **DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (27/02/2019) at position 0 (2): Unexpected character** ,, the date being passed is 27/01/2019

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use Laravel build in [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

`$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date);`

Then you can do `$date->toDateTimeString();` or whatever you want to do with the Carbon date object

Comment: I have tried and I get this error **(1/1) InvalidArgumentException

Unexpected data found.
Unexpected data found.
Trailing data**

Comment: Seems the format you supply is not correct you can check here how to compose the correct format http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Is your date with 4 digit year or with 2 digit year ? if it is 2 digits change the capital `Y` to `y`

Answer (score 0):

Encode it in json format and send it to the controller

Answer (score 0):

Changing input type text into date might help you.
eg: `<input type="date" .......>`

Answer (score 0):

You have the problem because forward slash (/) signifies American M/D/Y formatting in `strtotime` and in your example `28/02/2019` 28 is month. So `strtotime` returns `false`. I recommend you to use `Carbon` library as was said above or change `/` with `-` if you want your way:

`$dobCv = date("Y-d-m", strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $request->dob)));`